# Broken MSSQL provider in recent QGIS versions - has anyone experienced this?

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I recently moved from QGIS 2.2 to 2.4.0 and in the process the MSSQL spatial data provider appears to have stopped working properly (behaviour is also the same with 2.5.0).

QGIS will still connect to an MSSQL table and will display the geometry, however it is not possible to filter it with a query, the SRID is not being read from the `geometry_columns` table and more importantly it is not possible to commit any edits back to the database.

I am running SQL Server 2012 - the `geometry_columns` table is present and populated correctly and all tables have integer primary key columns, etc.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? I am a bit perplexed as I have never experienced any problems prior to updating to 2.4.0.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the check boxes near the bottom of the "New MSSQL Connection" window shown here. http://i.imgur.com/8yc3x9G.png

Comment: I don't think so, as these controls are not new additions from 2.2. I have tried selecting and unselecting 'Use estimated table parameters' but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be known and already solved in latest builds:

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11076

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2014-September/029076.html

and the following messages.

Comment: I've tried the most recent build (2.5.0-71) but still get the same problem. Attempts to filter an MSSQL layer result in the message `'QSqlQuery::exec: database not open'` being generated in the `Qt` message log - I don't know if that adds anything?